# Set a maxlength for the title input in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, title

I'm creating a new custom post type. But I need to limit the max length for the title. This is how I'm creating the field in my code:

```
array(
    'key' => 'title',
    'label' => 'Title',
    'name' => 'title',
    'type' => 'text',
    'required' => 1,
    'maxlength' => 65,
)
```

But the maxlength property isn't working. Is there a way to set this limit from code (not using a plugin) and only for this post type?

Comment: Just build your CPT as you normally would then apply the following filter to it afterwards:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-custom-post-type-title-word-length/